# firebase dynamic link created programmatically in swift doesn't work, no domain

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have configured firebase project with dynamic link, I have domain for DL. But when I creating shroten link programmatically then I get an error. This error I receive for target test and debug of project, but same code is using for release app and for it dynamic link works. Each project target have own firebase project and domain. I don't know why works only release version ?

```
Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command line with your bundleID, app_code and API key:

> curl -X POST --dump-header - -H "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier:
>   REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_BUNDLE_ID” -H "Accept: application/json" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -d
>   "{\"longDynamicLink\":\"https://REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_APP_CODE.app.goo.gl/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom%3Fq%3Djump\",\"suffix\":{\"option\":\"UNGUESSABLE\"}}"
>   "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY”

Let me know how it worked.

If this line was able to create short link, than  error in iOS code.

Comment: Already I tried, my output for each target have some warnings, but dynamic links are returned. I checked everything in the project and I don't know where is any mistake.

Comment: GoogleServices-Info.plist contains APIKey. You need to ensure that each of your targets contains right and up-to-date GoogleServices-Info.plist. If different targets has different bundleIDs (and possibly belongs to different Firebase Projects) than each target need to have it's own GoogleServices-Info.plist. Also ensure GoogleServices-Info.plist is not cached anywhere, delete your Xcode DerivedData directory, remove App(s) from Simulator/iPhone. Do clean re-build and check again.

Comment: Server will output this error if the REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY does not match the Firebase project that owns the REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_APP_CODE.

Comment: Yes right, this error appears in this situation. I checked everything what I could. Last chance is with your tip about DriverData directory :(

Comment: Solution with clean everything and restart unfortunately doesn't work :(

Comment: Replied to your Firebase support tickets with couple more steps to debug, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST --dump-header - -H "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier: com.debugbundlefromanotherfirebaseproject.debug" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"longDynamicLink\":\"https:\/\/RELEASE_DOMAIN.app.goo.gl\/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Egoogle%2Ecom%3Fq%3Djump\",\"suffix\":{\"option\":\"UNGUESSABLE\"}}" "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=API_KEY_RELEASE"
{
  "shortLink": "https://RELEASE_DOMAIN.app.goo.gl/EDKuPWwaXrFzfs4S2",
  "warning": [
    {
      "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
      "warningMessage": "Android app 'android.com.releaseandroidid' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent]"
    },
    {
      "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
      "warningMessage": "Android app 'android.com.debugeandroididfromanotherfirebaseproject' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent]"
    }
  ],
  "previewLink": "https://RELEASE_DOMAIN.app.goo.gl/EDKuPWwaXrFzfs4S2?d=1"
}
```

I think that could be problem in Firebase. Because for release project domain POST work although request have mistake bundle id, additional in result warnings contain one warning with android ID from another Firebase project. I am waiting for response from firebase. Example above.

Comment: We do allow creation of the short link with mismatched bundleID. This done intentionally to allow more flexibility for developer. For example, you can create short links for Apps that does not exists (yet). But when this short link is tapped, the bundleID will be checked and error will happens at this stage.